# Extracting specific html items using soup.find()

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull out a few items from some html i've brought into python using Beautiful Soup.

**Here is the html:**

```
[<div class="metadata container container-max-width-modifier">
 <div class="salary col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
 <i class="icon icon-pound"></i>
 <span itemprop="baseSalary" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/MonetaryAmount">
 <meta content="GBP" itemprop="currency"/>
 <span>£7.83 - £8.83 per hour</span>
 <span itemprop="value" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
 <meta content="7.8300" itemprop="value"/>
 <meta content="7.8300" itemprop="minValue"/>
 <meta content="8.8300" itemprop="maxValue"/>
 <meta content="HOUR" itemprop="unitText"/>
 </span>
 </span>
 </div>
 <div class="location col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
 <i class="icon icon-location-new"></i>
 <span id="jobCountry" value="Scotland"></span>
 <span>
 <a href="/jobs/jobs-in-aberdeen" itemprop="jobLocation" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
 <span itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
 <meta content="Aberdeenshire" itemprop="addressRegion"/>
 <span itemprop="addressLocality">Aberdeen</span>
 <meta content="GB" itemprop="addressCountry">
 </meta></span>
 </a>, <span>Aberdeenshire</span>
 </span>
 </div>
 <div class="time col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
 <i class="icon icon-clock"></i>
 <span content="FULL_TIME, PART_TIME" itemprop="employmentType">Permanent, full-time or part-time</span>
 <meta content="full-time or part-time" itemprop="workHours"/>
 </div>
 <div class="applications col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
 <i class="icon icon-applicants"></i>
                     Be one of the first ten applicants
                 </div>
 <ul itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" style="display:none">
 <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
 <meta content="1" itemprop="position"/>
 <ul itemprop="item" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
 <li>
 <meta content="https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/retail-jobs" itemprop="url"/>
 <meta content="Retail" itemprop="name"/>
 </li>
 </ul>
 <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
 <meta content="2" itemprop="position"/>
 <ul itemprop="item" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
 <li>
 <meta content="https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/retail-jobs" itemprop="url"/>
 <meta content="Other Retail" itemprop="name"/>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </li></li></ul>
```

**This is the code i've put together:**

```
salary_range = soup.find('div', class_="metadata container container-max-width-modifier").find('span', itemprop="baseSalary").text.strip()
salary_min = soup.find('div', class_="metadata container container-max-width-modifier").find('span', itemprop="value")
salary_time = soup.find('div', class_="metadata container container-max-width-modifier").find('span', itemprop="unitText")
job_location = soup.find('div', class_="location col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6").find('span', itemprop="addressLocality")
job_country = soup.find('div', class_="location col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6").find('span', id="jobCountry")
```

The first one works fine, for pulling out the salary range. I would like to have separate variables for: the unit (e.g. per hour, yearly, monthly, etc.),  minimum value, maximum value, job location, job country, full-time/part-time, and sector.

I think I can manage most of them myself, but the ones i'm specifically having trouble with are salary_min, salary_max, and unit (hour, yearly, monthly). For job_country and job_location it also returns the full html line where I just want the text in the speech marks.

If anyone can offer any insights on how to do this / do it better I would be very grateful!

Comment: Is it possible to share the url @Impossibility Theorem?

Comment: Sure! It's from here: https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/barista-costa-aberdeen-tesco/36178175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the three fields `Min Salary`,`Max Salary` and `Unit`, you can try using the below way. I used css selector within the script to give it a cleaner look:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/barista-costa-aberdeen-tesco/36178175"

res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
minSalary = soup.select_one('.salary meta[itemprop="minValue"]')["content"]
maxSalary = soup.select_one('.salary meta[itemprop="maxValue"]')["content"]
unit = soup.select_one('.salary meta[itemprop="unitText"]')["content"]
print(f'Min Salary: {minSalary}\nMax Salary: {maxSalary}\nUnit: {unit}')
```

Output it produces:

```
Min Salary: 7.8300
Max Salary: 8.8300
Unit: HOUR
```

Comment: Cheers SIM. This is awesome -- I really like the approach. I'm actually looping through thousands of these pages so will integrate this into my scraping function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's lxml library instead of BeautifulSoup, see the code below.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

req = requests.get('https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/barista-costa-aberdeen-tesco/36178175')
tree = html.fromstring(req.content)
salary_range = tree.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="baseSalary"]/span/text()')[0]
salary_min = tree.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="minValue"]/@content')[0]
salary_max = tree.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="maxValue"]/@content')[0]
salary_time = tree.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="unitText"]/@content')[0]
job_region = tree.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="addressRegion"]/@content')[0]
job_locality = tree.xpath('.//span[@itemprop="addressLocality"]/text()')[0]
job_country = tree.xpath('.//meta[@itemprop="addressCountry"]/@content')[0]

print('Salaray Range:', salary_range,'\n' 'Min Salary:', salary_min,'\n'
 'Max Salary:', salary_max,'\n' 'Salary Time:', salary_time,'\n'
 'Job Region:', job_region,'\n' 'Job Locality:', job_locality,'\n'
 'Job Country:', job_country)
```

Output

```
Salaray Range: £7.83 - £8.83 per hour
Min Salary: 7.8300
Max Salary: 8.8300
Salary Time: HOUR
Job Region: Aberdeenshire
Job Locality: Aberdeen
Job Country: GB
```

Comment: Thanks Sohan. This is really useful and shows me a neat alternative to the Beautiful Soup approach I was attempting.